# Yahoo OAuth question

Tags: python, oauth, yahoo

I'm keep getting oauth_problem=consumer_key_unknown error when trying oauth https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/get_request_token

I'm pretty sure my consumer key is correct because it works locally (Runs via 127.0.0.1). Just keep giving me oauth_problem=consumer_key_unknown when I try it on my server. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

is it sending the right domain in requireSession (4th argument should be something like 'http://mydomain.com/' which should match exactly what you used to sign up...

Comment: Are you referring to oauth_callback? I'm just following their guide here: http://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-auth-flow.html#oauth-requesttoken. Currently at step 2 which is where I encounter the error. The callback is within the same domain i sign up with.