# How can I get Yahoo OAuth to work when I develop locally when my local domain is not registered with Yahoo?

Tags: oauth, localhost, yahoo

I'm working on an app that uses Yahoo OAuth.  The OAuth had been working fine but I just registered my domain with Yahoo and now it will not let me use the OAuth when I develop locally because 
"Custom port is not allowed or the host is not registered with this consumer key."

The issue is because my call back URL is to a domain that is not registered with Yahoo (http://localhost:8080/welcome).

I'm not sure what to do.  I'm also new to development so if you could be specific with suggestions that would be awesome!  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you ever come up with a solution? Netflix and Google's OAuth work fine with localhost:8080 as the host for the callback.

Answer (score 27):

Hiii... yahoo works on localhost :).. what you have to do is while registering for a yahoo consumer key and secret key, the registration page asks you what type of application is yours. I guess it gives you two options , website and the oder one as stand alone app. Choose stand alone app as in your case. Then it will give you a pair of keys, and it will work on localhost :). Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  Totally worked!  Not sure what we would have done if we couldn't test prior to deployment...especially given the wonderful state of their docs :P  Thanks!

Comment: Feels great to see a comment for an answer that was helpful! Cheers!

Comment: Cool. Please accept this answer if you found this useful.

Comment: does not work when I create an app in YDN as installed app and then provide a callback_uri when requesting auth. it shows `uh oh seems like something went wrong` screen. any ideas what might be wrong?

Answer (score 8):

[It looks like Yahoo! doesn't want you to do this.](http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/ydn/general/localhost.html)   Some answers from similar questions might be helpful (or not):

- [How do I develop against OAuth locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670398/how-do-i-develop-against-oauth-locally)
- [401 Unauthorized using Yahoo OAuth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668793/401-unauthorized-using-yahoo-oauth)
- [Yahoo OAuth question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061124/yahoo-oauth-question)

EDIT: more evidence Yahoo! doesn't support this: http://developer.yahoo.net/forum/?showtopic=6496&cookiecheckonly=1

Answer (score 4):

I found the simplest solution was just to register for a separate key for my development environment. As long as you don't verify the domain for that key, you shouldn't hit any issues.

Answer (score 3):

After many attempts, I too came to the conclusion that Yahoo's **redirect_uri** does not seem to work with ports other than 80.

The one solution that worked for me:

1. Download [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)
2. Run the app and input **ngrok http xxxx** in the console - where **xxxx** is the port you are trying to access
3. The command will generate a http://xxxxxx.ngrok.io forwarding link that can be used for Yahoo's needs
4. Create a new **Installed Application** at https://developer.yahoo.com/apps/create/ and input http://xxxxxx.ngrok.io in the **Callback Domain** field.
5. Links should now work with this **redirect_uri**

Answer (score 1):

Addressing [Muhammad's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/331174/muhammad-adeel-zahid) comment in [Vignes's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/621756/vignesh-iyer) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5031760/4013921) here because I can't comment. You should be able to use a callback with a stand alone app if you specify `127.0.0.1` as the callback domain. You may also needed to change the port that your local server is listening to, because you cannot request that yahoo use e.g. port 8000. Make sure your local server is listening to port 80.

Answer (score 0):

As of writing, setting the **Application Type** to *Installed Application* and then leaving the **Callback Domain** blank will give you errors.

What works is configuring 127.0.0.1 as the **Callback Domain** for the app. This works regardless if you are choosing *Web Application* or *Installed Application* as the **Application Type**. However, Yahoo! does not accept callback URLs with ports in it so you have to make sure your app listens to port *80* (or 443 if https) when running locally.

Another less ideal option would be using some random non-existent domain like `local.dev.env.com` as **Callback Domain** and then [editing your hosts file](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/) by adding this:

```
127.0.0.1 local.dev.env.com
```

This will forward all requests on `local.dev.env.com` to `127.0.0.1`.